# Java crypto comparisons: Does SunJCE use native code?

Tags: java, encryption, jce

I wrote up a test to compare some Java crypto provider performance (pasted below).  I was surprised to find that the SunJCE implementation ended up being the fastest, since others (at least Apache Commons Crypto) relies on a native openssl implementation.

1. Does SunJCE use a native implementation as well?
2. Is there an issue with this test that's giving me incorrect/misleading results?

```
// Nss installed on mac via "brew install nss"
fun getProviders(): List<Provider> {
    return listOf(
        Security.getProvider("SunJCE"),
        sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(
            "--name=CryptoBenchmark\\n"
                    + "nssDbMode=noDb\\n"
                    + "nssLibraryDirectory=/usr/local/opt/nss/lib/\\n"
                    + "attributes=compatibility"),
        BouncyCastleProvider()
    )
}

fun blockCipherTests(providers: List<Provider>) {
    val ciphers = providers.map {
        try {
            Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", it)
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            println("Error getting cipher from provider $it: $t")
            throw t
        }
    }

    val key = SecretKeySpec(getUTF8Bytes("1234567890123456"),"AES");
    val iv = IvParameterSpec(getUTF8Bytes("1234567890123456"));
    val random = Random()

    ciphers.forEach {
        it.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    }

    // Crypto commons doesn't implement the provider interface(?) so instantiate that cipher separately
    val properties = Properties().apply {
        setProperty(CryptoCipherFactory.CLASSES_KEY, CryptoCipherFactory.CipherProvider.OPENSSL.getClassName());
    }
    val apacheCommonsCipher = Utils.getCipherInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", properties)
    apacheCommonsCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv)


    val data = ByteArray(1500)
    val out = ByteArray(1500)
    random.nextBytes(data)
    repeat (10) {
        ciphers.forEach { cipher ->
            val time = measureNanoTime {
                repeat(100) {
                    cipher.doFinal(data)
                }
            }
            println("Cipher ${cipher.provider} took ${time / 100} nanos/run")
        }
        // Run the apache test separately
        val time = measureNanoTime {
            repeat(100) {
                apacheCommonsCipher.doFinal(data, 0, 1000, out, 0)
            }
        }
        println("Cipher apache took ${time / 100} nanos/run")

        println("====================================")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val providers = getProviders()

    println(providers)

    blockCipherTests(providers)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. And no, it doesn't.

AES-NI is used through *Java intrinsics*, which replaces byte code by the native implementation of AES. So although you won't find a direct call to the AES-NI instructions, the `doFinal` call in your Java code will at some point use hardware acceleration. So the code of the JCE is just Java, but the JIT can still speed it up. Nifty, huh?

To really test your code you may want to use a warm up time for the JIT (to enable the AES-NI as well). You should be able to use a buffer instead of generating a new array object each time for the ciphertext.

More importantly, might want to catch the output of that buffer and e.g. XOR it into a final buffer and print it out. This will make it next to impossible for the compiler to skip the code altogether. Compiler optimizations are tricky to handle if you're not really interested in the results themselves; the compiler or JIT may just skip the encryption altogether to obtain the same result, after all.

You probably need more AES operations in a single loop too. You could implement the Monte Carlo testing required for the AES competition as a base.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  It's still surprising to me that it's faster than the wrapped openssl (which I would expect to be highly optimized) but maybe there's other overhead there?  The apache release is also quite old unfortunately.  I'll look at modifying the test with your suggestions as well.

Comment: It's surprising, but there are many ways of screwing up performance tests. Differences in buffer handling etc. may also be an issue. And having seen how OpenSSL is programmed I would not be surprised if there is an issue. Finally, you must of course make sure that it has been compiled with AES-NI support. It's likely the default for newer OpenSSL versions, but otherwise you're relying on a software implementation of AES that's likely also slow(ish) to avoid side channel attacks.